# Why does my one of my headers in my Nav Bar go to the next line when viewing Mobile?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm having some trouble trying to get my Nav Bar to adjust correctly when viewing on mobile devices. When I go to inspect (IPhone 12 Pro) the "about" link in my nav bar goes to the next line. I'm not sure why it does this when there is plenty of space for it to be on the same line above.

I'm not sure if this can be fixed with CSS or if it has to be done via a media query? Any guidance would be appreciated as I'm currently a newbie to coding.

Link to my website https://jpark42.github.io/portfolio-website/index.html

Comment: Please post your condensed html and css here.  See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you should post your code into your question and not have links to external websites that make us chase your code, i will happily try to land some help.

To have your links aligned even on small screens, follow these steps:

1. apply `align-items: center` to `.page-header`. This will vertically align the Facebook logo image and the links.
2. apply those rules to `.navigation-list` (you can keep the rules that were already applied):

```
display: flex; /** make the ".navigation-list" a flex container */
align-items: center; /** centers the links vertically */
justify-content: end; /** pushes the links to the far right */
flex-wrap: wrap; /** if the space is too small to display a link on the same line yhe browser will intelligently push the link(s) onto a next line */
margin: 0; /** removes the margins added by the browser (that should be done in a "reset" stylesheet) */
```

the above steps should bring you very close to your goal. To have better responsiveness, only the above rules won't suffice.

> Learn more about [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) on MDN.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I think I was able to figure it out. My apologies on making you chase the code to look for the answer. This is my first post on Stack and I will learn to be more specific when asking questions in the future!

Comment: @user19645175 Glad I managed to help.

Answer (score 0):

Even though its on 310px width (no phone has that width), you should readjust your margins and paddings. For example on ul element you should readjust padding:40px to padding:0, margins of li elements too. Your screen size is smaller, but margins and paddings are staying same. They are not so friendly to new people.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but if I made the padding for the ul element to 0 and the margins, wouldn't that make it all of the content clumped together when viewing from the desktop even though the problems would be solved on mobile?